# Why am i getting "File was not found in the executable" in stackdriver debug snapshot?

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver

The classname and line number are valid.
Does the source code also needs to be bundled with the binaries?

Comment: From Brad Daniels' comment-as-an-answer, which will likely be deleted soon: "StackDriver debugger snapshots are based on file and line number, not class and line number. How are you attempting to set the breakpoint? Please give more detail. The debugger should work even if you have no sources, though you'd need to use the `gcloud beta debug` command line interface to set snapshot in that case."

Answer (score 0):

The source code does **not** need to be bundled with the binaries. For java, the jar need to include file and line information (which is usually there by default).

To take a snapshot, you need to specify the **file** and line number, not the classname.  e.g., Foo.java:123